# Second Derivative Test: Can we relax hypothesis that $f$ is twice differentiable on neighborhood? (Counterexample)

Tags: calculus, analysis, examples-counterexamples

Second Derivative Test for Extrema:

> Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$  be a function that is twice-differentiable on $(c-\varepsilon,c+\varepsilon)$ for some $\varepsilon >0$. Suppose $f^{\prime}\left(c\right)=0$.
>
> 1. If $f^{\prime\prime}\left(c\right)<0$, then $c$ is a strict local maximum of $f$.
> 2. If $f^{\prime\prime}\left(c\right)>0$, then $c$ is a strict local minimum of $f$.

Can we delete "twice-" in the first sentence and just assume $f^{\prime\prime}(c)$ exists?

I'm guessing not but what might a counterexample be?

Comment: I suspect let f' = some *variation* of the Thomae function, meets the criteria
A. f' is integrable, so f exists
B. f'' ( c ) exists 

Or maybe f'' = thomae function?

Or a series of sawtooth functions with progressively higher frequencies?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function